# Can I use Simple Past in a subordinate clause with "while" when the main clause is in the Past Progressive?

Tags: past-simple, past-continuous, progressive-aspect

> I was reading while she slept.

Or should it necessarily be "I was reading while she was sleeping" or "I read while she slept"?

Can I use the Simple Past in a subordinate clause beginning with "while" when the tense of the main clause is the Past Progressive (Continuous)?

Comment: Yes, it's fine. One thing **was ongoing** when another happen**ed**.

Comment: Does this imply that she stopped sleeping before I stopped reading?

Comment: It is what I said: One thing was ongoing when another happened. During the TIME you were reading, she slept.

Comment: No. Your construction is perfectly idiomatic. It is used far more often than repetition of the progressive form. **I was writing this answer while you waited to receive it.**